# POST 500 (Internal Server Error) - Ajax & laravel 4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, laravel

Sorry if my explanation is bad.  Anyways, I have this todo list made by using laravel 4 sometime last year.  Been working great for the last few months and I stopped playing around with it.  Somehow I was playing around with it just yesterday and now it's giving me this POST 500 (internal Server ERROR).  The Ajax call was working perfectly before.  I had this error with chrome last night and today I tried using firefox, somehow it worked but then few minutes after, I am getting the same error in firefox too.  By the way, a few ajax call is used here. Adding an item uses ajax to post what's added with a done button (this ajax is working perfectly).  When the done button is clicked it should become a delete button and this is the ajax that's giving me the error.  I went to the `app.php` to turn the `debug => true` 
This error message is shown

`{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Creating default object from empty value","file":"\/home2
\/.........\/TodoController.php","line":174}}`

In my line 174 I have `$query->done = 1;`

that line is inside of this function

```
public function doubleDQuery($table, $id, $todoText, $done, $action){
    $query = $table::where('id', '=', $id)->where('todoText', '=', $todoText)
        ->where('done', '=', $done)->first();
    if($action == 'done'){
        $query->done = 1;
        $query->touch();
        $query->save();
    }

    if($action == 'delete'){
        $query->delete();
    }

}
```

if I commented out the `$query->done = 1`, it gives me an error to the next line

`{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to a member
 function touch() on a non-object","file":"\/home2\......\/TodoController
.php","line":175}}`

if I commented the above line up, it gives me the error of none-object to save().

No modification is done for the past months and it was working for like a minute in firefox as mentioned above.  I just have no idea where I should start looking for an answer, can someone give me a hand where I should start looking?

I have read that since 500 is internal server error it might be the server instead of my codes but it's weird that the other ajax call in the same application works just this is giving me the headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just means that `$query` is not what you think it is.

It seems to be `null` which means that there is no entry in the database matching your where clause. Although you expect it, respectively require it to be an object and also an instance of your model class for this code to work, without throwing an exception.

So you can either check for `null` manually and do whatever you wan't like:

```
if($query === null) {
    //No matching row found
}
```

Or use `firstOrFail()` instead of `first()` which will actually already throw an exception with a 404 status code which may be what you want because you probably want to handle it properly on the client side.

Comment: thanks, I will give it a try later but what might cause this since nothing is changed in the code / database and once I get the error, refreshing the page would show the changes are actually made even with the errors.

Comment: Can't really find anything else in the code you posted. The only thing I could imagine, which fits your description, is that you are somehow executing the ajax call twice. The first one does the change and the second one fails because `done` has changed in the database.

Comment: hummm, I just tried using a `vardump($query)` right after the $query variable to see what is returned, it does actually return the object in the database it'll be long to look at but it's something like this `["original":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "50"
    ["userID"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["todoText"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["done"]=>` but error still exists this means it's not null isn't it?

Comment: given what you suggested, I actually wrapped the if function that checks done / delete with if($query) and it works now.  It was quite stupid and not experienced enough to not check if it's null or not but as mentioned, it's weird though.  When I `var_dump($query)` it's not null at all, what might be the cause of this? ( I know it's hard to say much but just wonna get more ideas)

Comment: As I said, given what I know about your code I can only imagine that it is somehow executed twice. The first one worked and the second one failed.
If your code fails because the entry is `null`, it will definitely not update it.

Comment: umm, let me find and see if I can figure out where it's running twice. Definitely not good if it's running the query twice.